# How to fix install Comondo antivirus in kali linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, dpkg, deb

I want to install a antivirus software in kali linux. I find a software name Comondo : https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php.
I download deb file and run but failed, like this: [image]

How can I fix this problem? what is my problem, too?

Answer (score 1):

When trying to install the package you have downloaded, dpkg is telling you that it can't install it as it's missing some dependencies, so you will need to install them in order to be able to install Comodo AV. You need to downloaded the Debian package `can-linux_x64.deb` from the official Comodo website, and then:

```
sudo apt-get install /root/Downloads/can-linux_x64.deb
```

This command should install Comodo AV and all its dependencies.